# How to animate imageview from off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I have an imageview I put onto the view controller of a circle.

I would like to start that circle from off screen and move it to the location I've put it.

What would be the best way to animate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
-(void)viewWillAppear {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5
                          delay:5
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{
                             CGRect frame = view.frame;
                             frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-200;
                             frame.origin.x = 0;
                             view.frame = frame;
                         }completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
```

You many animation option's [UIViewAnimationOptions]

```
    UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut,
    UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear,
    UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft,
    UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp,
    UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve,
    UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop..
```

Comment: I do have a quick question- I've used the code and the circle has moved on screen. However there is not animation. When the view controller loads, the circle appears already moved on the screen. The circle is translated from the location it should be.

Comment: increase the delay time & animation time!

Comment: I did increase both the delay and anim time to 20000 and it's still displaying post animation.

Comment: bro.. keep it simple 10 ! not that much :)

Comment: I only used the large number to make sure the animation wasn't working quickly. I changed it to 10 and the circle is still displaying post animation. Sorry- I am very new to iOS :(

Comment: just to confirm `view` would be my imageview with the circle?

essentially `circle.frame`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138050/discussion-between-nikdange-me-and-airagale).

Answer (score 0):

You want to create your image view off-screen. Its easiest if you set it up in Interface Builder that way. you can create it on-screen, add a constraint to place it at the target location, note the value, and then change the constraint's constant so the view is moved off-screen.

Then control-drag the constraint into your view controller and create an outlet to it.

To animate the image view on-screen, change the constraint's constant value to the "on-screen" value you noted above, and then call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the view from inside an a UIView animateWithDuration block.

If you want to add the image view in code then you need to add it off-screen, add it as a subview, and then trigger a UIView animation to move it back on-screen. You should probably also do the positioning with constraints as outlined above, although it gets more complicated because you have to create those constraints in code.